# Get only first child of every .s class element on the page

Tags: jquery, children

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSB6X/)

Now, in this piece of code my aim is to get the text content of the first child of every  element with class `s` on the page.

If I write my code like this: `$("#m").find(".s").children().text()`, then it gets all children of `.s`.

But I only want the first child of every `.s`. Then I wrote this: `$("#m").find(".s").children().eq(0).text()`

Now my problem is I am unable to get the first child of **all** `.s` not the first child of the **first** `.s` element in the page. What should I do?

Comment: There is actually a first() method. http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: I haven't had the time to test this out, but try: $("#m").find(".s").children(":first-child").text()

Comment: can anyone explain me why children().eq(0) isn't working but children(":first-child") is working

Comment: `.children(':first-child')` selects all the elements (from the original set) that are first children of their parents. `.eq(0)` takes the whole list, and selects the first *one*. It doesn't care about parents, place in the DOM, etc. - `eq()` selects *at most* one element, always.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `first-child` pseudoclass:

```
alert($("#m").find(".s *:first-child").text());
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/fSB6X/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through all the matching `.s` elements.

```
$("#m").find(".s").each( function(){
    alert( $(this).children().eq(0).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fSB6X/4/